# Azure App service resource group on Sandbox. Created for learning does not allow Free Service plans

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My team is new to Azure.

We are getting them to practice, App hosting and plan creations. But every time we end up sharing subscriptions to too many users.

Steps followed are as follows:-

> 1. Create app name.
> 2. Subscription - using Concierge Subscription
> 3. Resource Group - Sandbox learn- XXXX- XXXX
> 4. Data Provider - MySQL
> 5. App Service Plan/Location :  :  :
> 6. Ok click
> 7. Create click

Error: You do not have access, The client '########' with object id '#########' does not have authorization to perform this action. 
'Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/triplecrown2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/XXXXXX' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. (Code: AuthorizationFailed)

Comment: What is your role of the subscription? Azure portal->All services->subscription

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You are creating a new app service plan and selecting the Free plan option (which is not selected by default), and when you click Create you are getting the above error?

Comment: App Services are not Service Fabric

Comment: @TonyJu "You don't have any subscriptions" is displayed under that table with subscription name, subscription id, subscription role, cost and status.

Comment: If you don't have a subscription, how can you create azure resource?

Comment: @Paul we are creating App Service plan, selecting Free plan F1 subscription.

Comment: @MickyD Agreed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have to login and start AZ-900 course path and then we get Sandbox for 3 hours, where it then works. Otherwise we get a page saying "Create a Free account - Explore Azure with a $200 credit for 30 days, 12 months of free products, and more than 25 products that are always free."